# Detecting File Download Completion Status on Android

Tags: java, android, io

i am downloading files from server with following code

```
conn=url.openConnection();
bytesTotal=conn.getContentLength();    
in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

while (true){
    byteFromStream=in.read(buffer);
    if (byteFromStream==-1) break;
    bytesLoaded=bytesLoaded+byteFromStream;
}
```

So i am basically counting number of bytes downloaded and matching it with bytesTotal.

At the end if bytesTotoal is not same as bytesLoaded i am saying download status is incomplete.

Problem is with 12 KB file size i am getting good success rate but with higher file size status is always incomplete.

is their any other way i can be certain about my download status.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're being hit by this (quoting from the HttpURLConnection documentation):

> By default, this implementation of HttpURLConnection requests that servers use gzip compression. Since getContentLength() returns the number of bytes transmitted, you cannot use that method to predict how many bytes can be read from getInputStream(). Instead, read that stream until it is exhausted: when read() returns -1. Gzip compression can be disabled by setting the acceptable encodings in the request header:

`urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");`

Comment: The source code currently **does** check "when `read()` returns `-1`", so it isn't helpful to include that part of the quotation.

Comment: @Carl: that to me seems like major nitpicking. A bigger flaw with my answer is that it's relevant only to HttpURLConnection, while the OP appears to be using a plain URLConnection. But it could be that getContentLength returns -1 for some of the files he's trying to download if their lengths aren't know, in which case he's obviously going to get a mismatch when comparing against bytesLoaded.

Comment: I agree it's nitpicking. However, after reading the question and then your answer, I thought that the answer to the question was to check the return value of `read()` and was surprised when I looked back at the question.

Comment: Actually i always get file size. One big red light is it always end-up downloading thousands byte less. example, like for 1k KB  i end up with around 7k KB .

Comment: Does the data you're able to download from those files look ok? What does getContentEncoding() for the connection give you?

Comment: I do not save data just count the data, but i assume that it is basic 8 bit char. Size never goes more then total size so my this assumption is basically right.